# Como comparar 3 variâncias diferentes?

Tags: r

Tenho 3 amostras diferentes de tamanho 5, média 100 e desvio padrão 12.

Como faço para comparar as 3 variâncias ao mesmo tempo? Sei que preciso fazer uma tabela nova, mas não tenho ideia de como fazer.

Comment: Por favor dê um exemplo de dados com `dput(x)`, onde `x` é uma amostra e o mesmo para as outras. Com tamanhos iguais a 5 deve ser fácil.

Answer (score 3):

Vou supor que as amostras são de variáveis normais, com média 100 e desvio padrão 12. Para testar a homogeneidade das variâncias, há o teste de Levene, que se pode encontrar no pacote `car`.

```
library(car)

set.seed(343)  # Torna o exemplo reprodutível

n <- 5
x <- rnorm(n, mean = 100, sd = 12)
y <- rnorm(n, mean = 100, sd = 12)
z <- rnorm(n, mean = 100, sd = 12)
```

Agora, juntamos as amostras numa variável `v` de uma `data.frame`, com um `factor`, a variável `f` que nos diz a qual amostra pertence cada linha da df.

```
dados <- data.frame(f = rep(letters[24:26], each = n), v = c(x, y, z))
leveneTest(v ~ f, data = dados, center = mean)
#Levene's Test for Homogeneity of Variance (center = mean)
#      Df F value Pr(>F)
#group  2  0.2198 0.8058
#      12
```

Uma forma alternativa, tendo em conta que referiu a tabela ANOVA, será usar as funções para o modelo linear, tanto `lm` como `aov`.

```
modelo <- aov(v ~ f, data = dados)
leveneTest(modelo, center = mean)
```

Os resultados são os mesmos.

**EDIÇÃO.**
Há também o teste de Brown-Forsythe, que apesar de talvez ser menos utilizado, pode ter vantagens, nomeadamente quanto à robustez. Uma função que realiza esse teste pode ser encontrada no pacote `onewaytests`.

```
library(onewaytests)


bf.test(v ~ f, data = dados)
#
#  Brown-Forsythe Test 
#--------------------------------------------------------- 
#  data : v and f 
#
#  statistic  : 0.156811 
#  num df     : 2 
#  denom df   : 11.3735 
#  p.value    : 0.8566824 
#
#  Result     : Difference is not statistically significant. 
#--------------------------------------------------------- 
#
```

Mais uma vez, não há evidência de heterogeneidade de variâncias. A hipótese nula não é rejeitada. Podemos portanto realizar um teste ANOVA para a diferença de médias, onde uma das assunções é precisamente a igualdade de variâncias.